# What needs to be provided within the recipient_signature_providers list of the Signer Object for a DocuSign Envelope?

Tags: python, docusignapi

DocuSign has a trusted signature provider option within the envelope creation process. To do this you provider the `recipient_signature_providers` option to the Signer object.

According to the swagger generated Signer object this value needs to be a list. Taken from the swagger code:

```
    @property
    def recipient_signature_providers(self):
        """Gets the recipient_signature_providers of this Signer.  # noqa: E501

          # noqa: E501

        :return: The recipient_signature_providers of this Signer.  # noqa: E501
        :rtype: list[RecipientSignatureProvider]
        """
        return self._recipient_signature_providers

    @recipient_signature_providers.setter
    def recipient_signature_providers(self, recipient_signature_providers):
        """Sets the recipient_signature_providers of this Signer.

          # noqa: E501

        :param recipient_signature_providers: The recipient_signature_providers of this Signer.  # noqa: E501
        :type: list[RecipientSignatureProvider]
        """
```

I know to get a list of available signature providers you can call the `AccountsApi.list_signature_providers()` which returns an `AccountSignatureProviders` object, that you can convert to a dictionary with `providers = AccountSignatureProviders.to_dict()` to make it useful and iterable. Then you can separate out the providers  via `providers[1]` and convert that to a json array, as you get an `INVALID_REQUEST_BODY...To fix this error change the JSON to a JSON array` if you don't. The output of this work is below:

```
[{'is_required': 'false'},
 {'priority': '1'},
 {'signature_provider_display_name': 'GlobalSign - Digital Signing Service (DSS) - Production'},
 {'signature_provider_id': '73'},
 {'signature_provider_name': 'globalsign_tsp'},
 {'signature_provider_options_metadata': None},
 {'signature_provider_required_options': None}]
```

Does anyone know what needs to be contained within this RecipientSignatureProvider list to get the correct signature provider set on the envelope? Providing the complete output above does not work, the API uses the default whenever this is provided.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was provided [this documentation](https://docusign.github.io/docusign-esign-python-client/docusign_esign/models/account_signature_providers.html#AccountSignatureProviders) from Docusign. This shows that you can retrieve the signature providers with the `AccountSignatureProviders.signature_providers`, this returns something that can be indexed. From here, to set the signature provider to the signer object you have to put it in a list like so `recipient_signature_providers=[AccountSignatureProviders.signature_providers[x]]` since it has to be a json array.